# Format float number to integer in JSP

Tags: jsp, integer, format

I am dealing with problem in JSP. Basically, I want to take float number such as 0.4311223 and turn it to 4 here is how I do it:

```
                <c:set var="age" value="${(0.4311223 * 10)}" />

                <fmt:formatNumber var="ageRatio"
                type="number"
                value="${age}"
                maxFractionDigits="0"/>

                Age ratio: ${ageRatio}<br />
```

It prints empty string, when I print ${age} it prints correct value of 4.311223.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you include the taglib?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Please try to add the `minFractionDigits` attribute. I think you can remove the `type` attribute too.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${age}" minFractionDigits="0" maxFractionDigits="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like that

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:formatNumber var="ageRatio" type="number" value="${(0.4311223 * 10)}" maxFractionDigits="0"/>
Age ratio: ${ageRatio}<br />
```